# If $x$ is the only element that $x^2=e$ then $x\in Z(G)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$G$ be a group.

$$Z(G)=\{u\in G\mid ua=au \quad \forall a\in G \}$$

If $x$ is the only element in $G$ that satisfies  $x^2=e$ then $x\in Z(G)$

Attempt:

1. $x^2=e$ then $(\forall g\in G),\; gb^2=g=b^2g$ then $gb=b^2gb^{-1}=gb=gb^{-1}\ldots$

   it is not good.
2. I considered cayley table to examine elements but it did not go well.
3. I considered conjugate things but couldnot create a reasonable way to solve this.

Comment: Nit-pick: $e$ satisfies $e^2 = e$, so if $x$ is the _only_ such element in $G$, then $x = e$.

Comment: well, I thought this $x$ is the only element other than $e$, so because of this I couldnot do it :(, thank you.

Comment: I really, really didn't mean it as an answer to the question. I meant to make you understand that you need to be more precise in your language, and say something like, for instance, "$x$ is the only element of order $2$", or "$x$ is the only non-trivial element which satisfies $x^2 = e$" or something. Because I'd be willing to bet money on that being the original intent of this exercise, rather than it being a trick question with the answer $x = e$.

Comment: I checked again, it is written as I did. I somehow expected more than that so I didnot think well. If a question is too easy, it is too hard :)

Comment: @user2312512851 Then there is a typo in the question which you were given. It is no big deal, but you should try to understand Arthur's point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Hint:* $o(gxg^{-1})=o(x)$.

$ {} {} {} $

Comment: I now understood that this element must be identity, at the beginning I thought it is different from $e$.

On the other hand, I cannot use this hint, to show $gx=xg\quad \forall g \in G$ if this hint helps to prove directly.

Comment: @userqrqh123 If two elements of a group commute, that says quite a lot about what happens if you conjugate one element by the other.

This correspondence goes the other way as well. 

lhf is telling you something about what happens when you conjugate $x$ by an element $g$. What he has written in this post is true for any elements of any group. However, you _know_ something about $x$, which you can use together with the above relationship to be even more specific about what happens when you conjugate $x$ by $g$. This may then be rearranged to show that $x$ and $g$ commute.